# Upgrading TexLive 2015 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, texlive

I am trying to compile one tex file in ubuntu 14.04LTS with TexLive2013/Debian. It gives the following error:

```
I can't find file tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex.
```

I tried to update TexLive to latest version using following commands from terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

But this does not seem to work. Still I am having same version of TexLive.

Regards,

Comment: FYI On 16.04 LTS the `tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex` file is located in [`texlive-pictures`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex). So you can try to install this package from PPA with `sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures`. If you do not have PPA, then this file will be located in [`pgf`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex) package on 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I downloaded the package available on 14.04LTS. Then I tried compiling the tex file. It is giving the same error. Do I need to specify any path?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/34

> Just a final comment in case someone has a similar problem: I've
>   installed texlive/2016 from another report and still not cigar.
>   Finally, saying `sudo apt-get remove pgf` did help. There is some
>   package confusion inside ubuntu, whereas it seems that wrong pgf was
>   being picked up.

***slosar commented on Nov 3, 2016***